# MySQL automatically change columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm really bad in MySQL, and I really don't know is it even possible. But I have 6k records and don't want to do it manually.

I have to columns: `Name` and `Slug`. Names can be different, for example `Dancer`, `Hip Hop`, `Rock (hard)`.

And what I want to do is for each record change `Slug` automatically depending on `Name`, with converting to slug. For example, for `Dancer` do `dancer`, for `Hip Hop` => `hip-hop`, for `Rock (hard)` => `rock-hard`.

Is it even possible?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/matoakley/1092571

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to update all your slugs in 1 query using [`LCASE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_lcase) and [`REPLACE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace). Something like this should work:

```
update mytable set Slug=lcase(replace(Name, ' ', '-'));
```

Comment: What about `Rock (hard)` => `rock-hard`?

Comment: The second word may also begin with an uppercase letter, but your solution would lowercase that too.

Comment: You can nest more replace calls to replace `(` and `)` with empty strings.

Comment: Thnx you for answer. `lcase` - it's for lower case. but what do `replace(Name, '  ', '-'));`

Comment: That replaces a space with a dash

Comment: @Asaph and how to insert additional rules? (for example not only spaces but dots too and delete `(`)

Comment: @AndreyDrozdov You can nest another call to `REPLACE()` for each character substitution. Your query may get long and tedious but it will work.